# CakePHP 2.x HABTM returning is no matching results

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a problem with habtm with cakephp and i dont know how to solve yet. I've got three tables: setores, veiculos e setores_veiculos.

**Setor model:**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Veiculo' => array(
        'className' => 'Veiculo',
        'joinTable' => 'setores_veiculos',
        'foreignKey' => 'setor_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'veiculo_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    )
);
```

**Veiculo model:**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Setor' => array(
        'className' => 'Setor',
        'joinTable' => 'setores_veiculos',
        'foreignKey' => 'veiculo_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'setor_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting'
    )
);
```

**In my setores controller i have:**

```
$options = array('conditions' => array('Setor.' . $this->Setor->primaryKey => $id));    
$setores = $this->Setor->find('first', $options);
```

**then in my debug:**

```
array(
'Setor' => array(
    'id' => (int) 5,
    'nome' => '2º Batalhão',
    'secretaria_id' => (int) 6,
    'sigla' => '2º BPM',
    'status_id' => (int) 1
),
'Veiculo' => array()
)
```

I can not understand why the Veiculo (vehicle) are not being listed. The insertion is working perfectly.

I expected:

```
 'Veiculo' => array(
     0 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Corolla'
     ),
     1 => array(
          'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Hillux'
    )
  );
```

In my veiculos controller the setores are being listed. Any suggestion?

*Thank you in advance and sorry about my english.*

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. Try changing

```
'unique' => 'keepExisting'
```

to

```
'unique' => true
```

At present, I go by the simple rules as explained in the documentation that if I am using a simple link table, i.e. not storing any data in it, I use **HABTM** and **unique set to true**, otherwise I use **hasMany through (The Join Model)** and **unique set to keepExisting** so as not to lose extra stored data.

Post a data dump of setores_veiculos.